# Understanding OAuth 2.0 and implementing it on a .NET app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, auth0

I am relatively new to the field and I am trying to understand more about how OAuth 2.0 works and how it can be implemented. I have an application (.NET) that communicates locally with a server to get and post data and I am trying to implement a protocol such as OAuth 2.0 that will make the connection between the client and the server secure. I understand the basic concepts of OAuth 2.0 but I do not know if I have to sign up with an account to a service that offers this protocol, such as Auth0, and how it can be used locally without the need of verifying anything over the internet.

Comment: I think you should refer to Auth0 documentation and it's quickstarts. This is a broad question and StackOverflow is not the best place for looking for an answer to this type of question. :)

Comment: maybe you can refer to [it](https://auth0.com/docs/dev-lifecycle/local-testing-and-development)